# How to use callback results in asynchronous model C++

Tags: c++

I have a C++ API which has a certain defined functions and it's related callbacks.
All these functions are asynchronous in nature.

Now, using this API I want to construct an asynchronous system which sends
multiple request to the server for collecting different data items and then use
these data item for further use.

For example:

```
void functionA()
    {
      requestDataForA(); //asynchronous request to the server
     //async wait for the callback 
      processDataForA(); 
    }

void functionB()
    {
      requestDataForB(); //asynchronous request to the server
     //async wait for the callback 
      processDataForB(); 
    }
void functionC()
    {
      requestDataForC(); //asynchronous request to the server
     //async wait for the callback
      processDataForC(); 
    }
```

Now my question is that when the callback gives the data item, how to use it for subsequent processing. It cannot be done in callback as callback doesn't know who will use the data.

Thanks
Shiv

Answer (score 1):

You implicitly have this information, you just need to track it. Lets say that object `A` calls `functionA`, you should make `A` implement a particular interface that accepts data related that is the response from calling `requestA`. Lets say this response is `DataA`, then the interface would be

```
class InterfaceADataHandler
{
public:
  virtual void handle(DataA const&) = 0; // this is the method that will process the data..
};

class A : public InterfaceADataHandler
{
public:

  void handle(DataA const&) {} // do something with data

  // Now I want to be called back
  void foo()
  {
    functionA(this); // call function A with this instance
  }
};

void functionA(InterfaceADataHandler* pHandler)
{
  // store this handler against request (say some id)
  request..();

  // wait for callback
  // when you have callback, lookup the handler that requested the data, and call that handler
}
```

Comment: When you say store handler against request, what does that mean?
Also, I don't want to wait for callback as I want to do other things in meanwhile. Say, I request data and start doing something else. Now, whenever callback is ready, it should somehow queue the function to be executed based on the result.

Comment: @shivchawla, let's say that it's possible to call `requestA` multiple times - how would you associate each callback with each request? You can assign some number - say request id against each request. So, have a map (e.g `map<request_id, InterfaceADataHandler*>`), now your API internally will have the callback handler from `requestA`, in that handler you'll find the real handler to call from the map above based on the request_id, and call that.

Comment: If I have to request multiple data items before I start some real work, then this mapping wont work as there would be multiple callback functions. So a handler for composed async operations is something which might solve this problem. In someway, all the intermediate request have to be hooked with same completion handler.

Answer (score 0):

In most API's, you the developer would be providing the callback which will be invoked by the API with the data that has been retrieved. You can then store the data and use it at a later time or use it within the callback (assuming that you won't take very long to process and promise not to block for I/O).

The model would look more like:

```
void functionA()
{
  requestDataForA(processDataForA); //asynchronous request to the server
}

void processDataForA(void *someData)
{
    // process "someData"
}
```