# Handling composite asynchronous functions in c++

Tags: c++, asynchronous, callback

I have an API which sends/receives request/data from the serve in an asynchronous manner. The API comes with request functions and their corresponding callbacks.

I intend to use this API but a single function in my application can send multiple asynchronous requests to the server before it starts doing anything on its own. Is there any framework to manage composite asynchronous functions.

An example would be

```
   void doSomething()
   {
      sendRequestDataItem1();  //receives result in getDataItem1()
      sendRequestDataItem2();  //receives result in getDataItem2()
      sendRequestDataItem3();  //receives result in getDataItem3()

      //this function can either be a composite handler or something else 
      NowDoSomethingMore();
   }
```

Thanks
Shiv

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to use callback results in asynchronous model C++](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7892274/how-to-use-callback-results-in-asynchronous-model-c)

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend `boost::signals`, it is pretty easy to use.

If you need thread safety (guessing?) [boost::siganals2](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_47_0/doc/html/signals2.html) is a good place to start.